# Does the C series from Bombardier incorporate composite materials into the fuselage and/or wings?

Tags: airbus, aircraft-development, composite-materials, bombardier, airbus-a220

Does the C series from Bombardier incorporate composite materials into the fuselage and/or wings? If so, what material is used, and where is it applied. Because of Airbus's 50% market share in the project there might be different technologies applied. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Airbus deal is fairly recent, are you asking if that could influence future design changes?

Comment: I am asking if there is a use of composited in any component of the C series.